# fnstenv on 64 bit returning wrong value?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, shellcode, x87

I'm using `fnstenv` FPU instruction to get the EIP in a 64 bit shellcode. Running it in GDB everything looks fine:

```
 0x0000000000400080  ? fldz   
 0x0000000000400082  ? fnstenv [rsp-0xc]
```

After running these instructions by stepping in with `si` I get in the stack the right value (0x0000000000400082).

What I miss is this: if I place a breakpoint after the `fnstenv` and then with `continue` I execute without a breakpoint between them, I get a wrong value: 0x0000003300400082.
The 0x00000033 is the value of CS register...not sure if this is a coincidence or not.

I'm using nasm and ld with the following syntax:

```
nasm -f elf64 shell.asm -o shell.o
ld shell.o -o sh --omagic
```

Comment: Can you include the complete source code?

Comment: `fnstenv` is not 64 bit aware, so you only get the low 32 bits of RIP which is EIP as you said, but printed it wrong. The following word indeed contains the `CS` selector.  That said, `gdb` indeed behaves strangely when using `si`, I don't even get a valid dump. The correct behavior is the second one.  PS: what's wrong with something along the lines of `lea rax, [rip]`?

Comment: Also note that you need 28 bytes of memory so the `rsp-0xc` is very suspicious even if it's not relevant to the current issue.

Comment: This is the complete source code.
I cannot use a lea because I have some restrictions in opcodes, so that's why I'm using this...but if it's not supposed to work for 64 bits, I guess I need to find another way.

Comment: There is `fxsave64` but that doesn't work for me at all. Surely you can do `syscall` though? That sets `rcx` to `rip`.

Comment: Good point...I need  to try these out....Thanks!